# Can't run powershell as administrator

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run as powershell script as administrator on a windows server 2012 r2. The problem is that as soon as I start the script as admin it shutdown with out running it. The script works if I start powershell ISE and run the scripte as admin from there. Is there a setting I am missing?

Comment: What shuts down exactly? Maybe posting a screenshot would help clarify.

Comment: I would suggest watching it in sysinternals process explorer and see if I can get some more information.

Comment: @Zaratara OK, can you open a PowerShell console as Administrator? Then run script from the console. What happens?

Comment: That works with out problems. It is just when I run .ps1 that it doesn't work

Comment: @Zaratara I see. Your problem is that your script requires Administrator elevation. When you launch from .ps1 file it does not get that. Have a look at this article [PowerShell Script that Relaunches as Admin](https://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2013/04/05/powershell-script-that-relaunches-as-admin/) It has all the code you need. Alternatively, if you can, turn UAC off.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe execution of scripts is disabled. Try running this first.

```
set-executionpolicy -unrestricted
```

Comment: I have tried this as well and it won't solve the problem with the powershell closing when I run it as admin.

Comment: Is there no message? Did you look in the event logs?

Answer (score 0):

I set the cmd on Windows Server 2012 to always run as admin this way:

```
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers" /v "c:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" /t REG_SZ /d "RUNASADMIN" /f
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers" /v "c:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe" /t REG_SZ /d "RUNASADMIN" /f
REG ADD "HKU\.DEFAULT\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers" /v "c:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" /t REG_SZ /d "RUNASADMIN" /f
REG ADD "HKU\.DEFAULT\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers" /v "c:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe" /t REG_SZ /d "RUNASADMIN" /f
REG ADD "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers" /v "c:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" /t REG_SZ /d "RUNASADMIN" /f
REG ADD "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers" /v "c:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe" /t REG_SZ /d "RUNASADMIN" /f
```

Maybe it will work with powershell too.